# "Stack Exchange Moderator Elections Begin" blog post has broken links

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link

The blog post [Stack Exchange Moderator Elections Begin](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) has two broken links:

1. The "over 60 days" link:

> [image]

It points to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/our-first-area-51-site-goes-public/ however since the post was written on October 1, 2010 the correct link is https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/our-first-area-51-site-goes-public/. Not sure if the link was originally broken, or broke after the migration to the new blog platform, but it doesn't really matter.

2. The "multiple moderator appointments and elections on the trilogy" link:

> [image]

The link points to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/moderators/ however after the migration, "categories" became "tags", so proper link is https://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderators/.

As a bonus to whomever fixing this, the list formatting is also borked:

> [image]

Should be 1, 2, 3, and formatted as list, probably.